# how can I get all the name of all tables in a sqlite database by using c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to get all tables name of a SQLite database but failed, here is my code.

Image :

[image]

```
   SQLiteConnection dbConnection;
        dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="+name+".sqlite;Version=3;");
        dbConnection.Open();
        String query = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " +
               "WHERE type = 'table'" +
               " ORDER BY 1";
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbConnection))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(rdr);      
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your query and code looks ok - what issues do you have with it ? Do you get any error message, or stack trace ? (Post that, as it appears without editing it). Does your database file actually have any tables - and are you certain you open the database file that you intend to open ? it's easy to mix up relative paths when you open a database file.

Comment: What's with that `ORDER BY 1`?

Comment: I don't get any error messages.  it simply returns nothing to me after I execute sql